# How do I get this jQuery script to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bit of jQuery code I am trying to get to work here. I basically have a vertical nav menu with two items that have jQuery dropdown menus that pop out to the side. However, when you hover over them both quickly they are displayed overlapping each other. So what I am trying to accomplish is that if one is hovered on and pops out, if the other one is already displayed it will slideUp and be hidden. The dropdown trucks already existed I am adding on the engines one. I will keep working on it but if anyone can help out I would appreciate it.

```
/* Dropdown Menu Trucks*/
$("#menu-main-menu .show-dropdown").hover(function(){
    $("#dropdown").slideDown('fast');
});

$("#dropdown").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#dropdown").show();
});

$("#dropdown").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#dropdown").slideUp('fast');
});

// ----------------------------

/* Dropdown Menu Engines */
$("#menu-main-menu .show-dropdown2").hover(function(){
    $(".dropdown-engines").slideDown('fast');
});

$(".dropdown-engines").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".dropdown-engines").show();
});

$(".dropdown-engines").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".dropdown-engines").slideUp('fast');
});

if ($('#dropdown').is(':visible')) {
    $(".dropdown-engines").slideUp();
}
else if ($('.dropdown-engines').is(':visible')) {
    $("#dropdown").slideUp();   
}
```

edit: let me approach this another way that seems easier to accomplish..

```
$("#menu-main-menu .dropdown2").hover(function(){  // hover over .dropdown2 
                                                   // show #dropdown-engine
    $("#dropdown-engine").slideDown('fast');
});

$("#dropdown-engine").mouseenter(function(){      // mouse enter #dropdown-engine
                                                  // show #dropdown-engine
    $("#dropdown-engine").show();
});

$(".dropdown2" || "#dropdown-engine").mouseleave(function(){

    $("#dropdown-engine").slideUp('fast');       // mouse leave #dropdown-engine
                                                 // *or .dropdown2 slideup
});                                              // but only if not hovering on either
```

Comment: Make a fiddle, and someone will be more likely to help.

Comment: Indeed, include the HTML

Comment: Use the [jQuery Hover Intent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) - this plugin adds a small delay to the trigger to fix just this issue.

Comment: Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2gemen6n/10/ I can't recreate what it is doing now but this basicall shows what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using hide(); on hover to hide the element I didn't want to see. I was severely overthinking this. Thanks to anyone who answered.

Answer (score 2):

The question isn't completely clear to me, but I think this is want.
I noticed that you used id's that are not present in your jsfiddle and are using classes and id's mixed. Try to be consistent and think DRY, by using data-target and the classes like in the example, the code is cleaner and shorter.

```js
$(function(){
    $(".dropdown").hide();//hide all dropdowns on start
    $(".show-dropdown").mouseenter(function(){
        //on mouse enter of a .show-dropdown, we slideup all .dropdowns
        $(".dropdown").slideUp("fast");
        //then we get the ID of the dropdown we want to show through the data-target attribute, and slide it down.
        $("#"+$(this).attr("data-target")).slideDown("fast");
    });
});
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="show-dropdown" data-target="dropdown-trucks"><!--data target is the ID of dropdown you want to show-->
      <a href="#">Trucks</a>
    </li>
    <li class="show-dropdown" data-target="dropdown-engines">
      <a href="#">Engines</a>
    </li>
</ul>



<ul id="dropdown-trucks" class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">Truck 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Truck 2</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="dropdown-engines" class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">Detroit Series 60 Engine</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cummins N14 Engine</a></li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes the fiddle is most likely not the same as what I'm working with, I tried to throw it together quickly. I am working with a custom WordPress theme that was not designed for anyone else to modify easily. Ideally I would just add sub menu items in the WP menus settings and it would automatically do what I need but they did this in a separate js file and 2 different style sheets. The reason for the mixed IDs and Classes is because they dynamically added the ID to the li for trucks using PHP and I am not great with PHP so I used a plugin to add a class to the li for engines.

Comment: I will try your solution and see if I can get it to work with what I already have, thanks